# Let $G$ be an abelian group. Let $\phi$ be a morphism on $G$. Can I say that $\phi(a)\cdot \phi(b)=\phi(b) \cdot \phi(a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question is this one:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group. Let $\phi$ be a morphism on $G$. Can I say that $\phi(a)\cdot \phi(b)=\phi(b) \cdot \phi(a)$, with $a$ and $b$ elements of $G$?

Comment: Yes $ab=ba$ thus $\phi(ab)=\phi(ba)$ and therefore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for **every** mapping $\phi:G\to G$! Being a morphism is irrelevant. For all $a,b\in G$, $\phi(a),\phi(b)\in G$ and therefore these elements commute!

Comment: He said "morphism", so it may be of the form $G\to H$; with $H$ not necessarily abelian. The point is the image will always be an abelian subgroup of $H$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff He said morphism **on $G$**.

Comment: To me that means the domain of the morphism is $G$. A morphism (defined) on $G$ is a morphism $G\to H$ for some $H$. It is not necessarily true that $G=H$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I agree it is likely what the op had in mind, yet the formulation is ambigous.

Comment: I thought it was clear enough. I meant $G \to G$.

Comment: @user215565 I also understood it this way. OK, then being a morphism is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course. This is because $ab=ba$, so $\phi(ab)=\phi(ba)\ldots$